# deactivating an active plugin using if page

Tags: php, functions

Good day! just wondering if you can help me out? I was trying to create a code for functions.php if the user currently lands on a specific page, thus the plugin will turn deactivated, but if the user re jumps on other pages, the plugin would be re activated.

Here's my code.

```
function disable_plugins(){
if( is_page(2690) ) {
    deactivate_plugins( '/popup-maker/popup-maker.php');
} else {
    //reactivate the plugin
}
} add_filter('option_active_plugins', 'disable_plugins');
```

Comment: This is entirely the wrong approach. It should not be necessary to disable a plugin entirely just because you don't want a pop-up to appear on a single page. It's overkill, and a hack. Look at the plugin's documentation to find a supported way to disable the pop-up on a specific page, or ask the author for help. If that doesn't work find a plugin that does support this feature.

Comment: if you deactivate a plugin by a users page visit, you would deactivate it entirely, also for every other user.. so yeah, your approach is kinda wrong here..

Answer (score 2):

Instead of deactivating the plugin completely (which would deactivate it everywhere on your site) look at the plugin's code and determine what JS and CSS it is enqueuing. Then in your theme's `functions.php` you can dequeue that plugin's JS/CSS - but only on whatever pages you want to disable the plugin on.

So for example, for the plugin Authorizer, if you want to remove the CSS from two pages, "about" and "contact":

```
add_action('wp_print_styles', 'wpse_317011_dequeue_authorizer');
function wpse_317011_dequeue_authorizer() {
    if(is_page('about') || is_page('contact')) {
        wp_dequeue_style('authorizer-public-css');
        wp_deregister_style('authorizer-public-css');
    }
}
```

Just replace `authorizer-public-css` with whatever CSS file you need to from your specific plugin. And dequeue JS as well, if that's needed.

Other conditionals like `is_singular()` work here too in case it's not just Pages you're dealing with.